# Corel Draw - Join two nodes to erase a vector line to vinyl cut

Tags: corel-draw, dieline, diecut

I'm somewhat new to Corel Draw and I have an image (see below) which I want to cut with a vinyl cutter. It includes the dielines that the cutter will cut but I had to do some modifications and I want to join two nodes. When I join them there's a line that is like a path between the two nodes.

Should I delete it so the plotter will not cut that line and ruin the image or will it not interfere with cutting?

[image]

Comment: Seemingly you wanted to create some new nodes at the edge of your red shape for refining the curve, but you generatd a new line instead. Moving the 2 new nodes do not affect the red shape, only the new line moves. Now you want to know, how to insert new nodes to the ege of your old shape. Right?

Comment: Ah, I see. Well if that would work then yes. @user287001

Answer (score 1):

For cutting there should exist exactly those paths that the cutter should slash along. Remove the extra paths. Select your extra line and press DEL. It should vanish and the 2 nodes, too.

If you're already succeeded to split your shape to 2 adjacent, but separate parts, this does not work. You must combine those parts again to one or (a more sure way) load from file your previous version that you know not having any obscure faults. If you're a beginner, you should save often and change the filename, too to keep possible to return back.

Hopefully you work in the same layer where your shape is. If not, then go into it.

You have the right tool selected. This is the curve editing tool. Hover the cursor over a curve, you see, when you are near enough -  there is an indicator symbol (tilde).

If you press the mouse button and move the cursor, the curve moves, but the change is in the nearest old nodes. If you double click on the curve, you create a new node. That can be moved and its Bezier handles can be adjusted.

Do not kill an unwanted node by DEL because the result may be quite unexpected. You kill a piece of the curve, too and replace it with one drawn between the adjacent nodes with their old handle settings.

Double click on the unwanted node to remove it and have the curve otherwise as unchanged as possible. The handles in the adjacent nodes adapt intelligently.